# “To hear” or “hearing”

Tags: comparatives, gerund-vs-infinitive

> Nothing is so happy as to hear from your family.
>
> Nothing is so happy as hearing from your family.

Which is more natural for native speakers?

Comment: A native speaker would not use *nothing is so happy* in this way, so the short answer is neither. See also *[How does one know when to use a gerund or a infinitive?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/384)* and *[Infinitive or Gerund](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92077)*.

Answer (score -3):

Hearing. Since you have a verb ending in -ing, hearing is grammatically correct and sounds more natural.

Comment: Well, yes, but the sentence is still wrong. You can't say _Nothing is so happy as hearing from your family_ any more than you can the other option.